# How can I repeat a wait_for-event after an incorrect input?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I want to check messages with my bot after a message has been sent. For this I use a `wait_for` event. I have defined this as follows:

```py
        try:
            messagecheck = await self.bot.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=10)
            if messagecheck.content == "!test":
                await ctx.send(f "Good job.")
            else:
                await ctx.send("Bad job.")
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await ctx.send("Timeout")
```

However, it is possible that you accidentally enter `!tes` or other possibilities in the channel. This will trigger the event, but it should not. I just want it to be wrong, for example, if you enter "!test 1" and otherwise let all other messages through without triggering the event. Is something like this possible?

Comment: Commands get picked up by the bot's main `on_message` handler and processed, so you need to override that or don't use a message that starts with your command prefix `!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a while loop to loop until content != "!test"

```py
try:
    msg = await self.bot.wait_for("message", check=check, timeout=10)
    while msg.content != "!test":
        await ctx.send("Bad Job")
        msg = await self.bot.wait_for("message", check=check, timeout=10)
    await ctx.send("Good Job")
except asyncio.TimeoutError:
    await ctx.send("Timeout")
```